# how to get complete info of webpage it has 3 divisions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape webpage

https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618

it has the 3 divisions. when ever I check for view source manually I am getting for only one division data where I have the cursor.  with code

```
 driver = webdriver.Ie()
 driver.get('https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618')
 content = driver.page_source
```

page_source also gives the one division data.

if I try to change the frame using

```
    driver.switch_to_frame(1)
```

I am getting an error no such frame available.  website is with JavaScript.

any help?

Comment: division means.. can you specify the exact data you want to extract . add a image or HTML code where you need to point it out

Comment: have you tried my code in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page has two frames and you have name and id. You can switch with anyone of them

```
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('menu'))
```

OR

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('viewer'))
```

Use `driver.switch_to.default_content()` to switch to default

[image]

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with name == viewer   ...... always second call is giving this error.

Comment: you can't use both at the same time. you can use anyone and then we need to switch back to default

Comment: try with directly switching to viewer and then try

Comment: wrote the command    driver.switch_to.default_content() in between the switch to frame worked well..

Comment: Yes that exactly what I said to use too ... Glad it work for you

Answer (score 0):

As you have clearly observed that there are `3 divisions`, the `Top Window` and `2 frames`, hence we can get the `page source` of the `Top Window` and then traverse through the `2 frames` to scrape the `page source` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie(r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(r'https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618')
content = driver.page_source
print("Content on Top Window is :")
print(content)
multiple_frames = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
print("There are " +str(len(multiple_frames)) +" frames")
for frame_name in multiple_frames:
    print("Content on "+frame_name.get_attribute("name")+" frame is : ")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame_name)
    sub_content = driver.page_source
    print(sub_content)
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.quit()
```

Output on the console is:

```
Content on Top Window is :
<html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dot="http://www.volpe.dot.gov" xml:lang="en"><head>
      <title>NASS Case Viewer - CaseID:773013618</title>
      <link id="StyleOut" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="output" href="StyleOut.css" /><script src="main.js"></script></head>
   <body onload="javascript:init('True','/NASS/CDS/XSLT/','773013618','case.xsl','CaseForm','Crash')">
...
...
...
</body></html>
There are 2 frames
Content on menu frame is : 
<html xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dot="http://www.volpe.dot.gov" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"><head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" />
      <title>menu</title>
...
...
...
                </script></head></html>
Content on viewer frame is : 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg-20000303-stylable" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"><head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Case</title>
      <link id="StyleOut" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="output" href="StyleOut.css" />
   </head>
   <body id="bodyMain">
...
...
...
</body></html>
```